# python - closing firefox browser down when complete

Tags: python, firefox

I am using driver.close() on the following code to close down the firefox browser when the code has finished but I get an error thrown after the first loop. Am I using it correctly?

error:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it

code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print('Firefox started')
print('Iterating links')
connection = pymysql.connect(host='.com', user='', password='', db='', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with connection.cursor() as cursor2:
    cursor2.execute("Delete from todaysmarkets")
for link in links:
    try:
        print('Fetching from link: ' + base + link)
        driver.get(base+link)
        print('Waiting for all the data to get loaded')
        element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"current")))
        print('Parsing page')
        tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
        names = tree.xpath('//*[@id="lpTable1"]/div[h3[text()=" Goal Supremacy and Goal Markets "]]/div/table/tbody/tr[not(@style="display: none;")]/td/span/text()')
        print(str(len(names)) + ' markets found')
        sells = tree.xpath('//*[@id="lpTable1"]/div[h3[text()=" Goal Supremacy and Goal Markets "]]/div/table/tbody/tr[not(@style="display: none;")]/td[3]/button/text()')
        buys = tree.xpath('//*[@id="lpTable1"]/div[h3[text()=" Goal Supremacy and Goal Markets "]]/div/table/tbody/tr[not(@style="display: none;")]/td[4]/button/text()')
        if(len(buys) != len(sells) or (len(buys) == 0 or len(sells) == 0)):
            print('Error fetching markets either suspended or does not exist')
            continue
        print('Putting markets into excel file')
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            for i in range(0, len(names)):
                cursor.execute(("INSERT INTO todaysmarkets(URL,Name,value) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"), (base+link,names[i], str((float(sells[i])+float(buys[i]))/2.0)))



           # ws.append([names[i], str((float(sells[i])+float(buys[i]))/2.0)])  
    finally:
        print('Saving the file with name markets.xlsx')
        driver.close()
```

Comment: It looks like you only open the driver once and then close it after the first loop. So when you try to use it again it's closed

Comment: Also, the function should be [`driver.quit()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver.WebDriver.quit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `driver.close()` (which should be `driver.quit()`) is done too soon.

You need to put after all your work is done, so after your `for`.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print('Firefox started')
print('Iterating links')
connection = pymysql.connect(host='.com', user='', password='', db='', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with connection.cursor() as cursor2:
    cursor2.execute("Delete from todaysmarkets")
for link in links:
    try:
        print('Fetching from link: ' + base + link)
        driver.get(base+link)
        print('Waiting for all the data to get loaded')
        element = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"current")))
        print('Parsing page')
        tree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
        names = tree.xpath('//*[@id="lpTable1"]/div[h3[text()=" Goal Supremacy and Goal Markets "]]/div/table/tbody/tr[not(@style="display: none;")]/td/span/text()')
        print(str(len(names)) + ' markets found')
        sells = tree.xpath('//*[@id="lpTable1"]/div[h3[text()=" Goal Supremacy and Goal Markets "]]/div/table/tbody/tr[not(@style="display: none;")]/td[3]/button/text()')
        buys = tree.xpath('//*[@id="lpTable1"]/div[h3[text()=" Goal Supremacy and Goal Markets "]]/div/table/tbody/tr[not(@style="display: none;")]/td[4]/button/text()')
        if(len(buys) != len(sells) or (len(buys) == 0 or len(sells) == 0)):
            print('Error fetching markets either suspended or does not exist')
            continue
        print('Putting markets into excel file')
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            for i in range(0, len(names)):
                cursor.execute(("INSERT INTO todaysmarkets(URL,Name,value) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"), (base+link,names[i], str((float(sells[i])+float(buys[i]))/2.0)))



           # ws.append([names[i], str((float(sells[i])+float(buys[i]))/2.0)])  
    finally:
        print('Saving the file with name markets.xlsx')

# Close driver at the end of the work
driver.quit()
```